# How to Start working with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

Hi I want to learn Hadoop.I have basic idea on how hadoop works with MapReduce framework.
Now i want to practice on my local PC so i want to know how to install hadoop on single Node.
I installed VM Workstation 10 and i tried to install any Linux flavour Operating system to install Hadoop , but iam not able to load Ubuntu into VM ware Workstation ,iam getting error as Exiting intel ...,Operating Not found  message.

Can any one please provide me steps on how to start with Hadoop installation.
Should i go for any Distributions(Cloudera,Hortonworks,MapR).If that is simple then tell me how to install those distributions.(I tried even with Cloudera importing vmware file into VMWare workstation it did not worked for me)

Comment: you are looking for discussion and advice. this is not a place for that.!!

Comment: http://lynda.com is the best resource.

Comment: Oh then what can be discussed here?I think this is forum where we get smart and good solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [VM given by Udacity for its course on Hadoop](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1v0zGBZ6EHap-Smsr3x3sGGpDW-54m82kDpPKC2M6uiY/pub). I found it really easy to set up.

Comment: Thank u , i will try and let u know.Started downloading

Comment: I used winzip/7zip to extract the zip file both are unable to extract data .With Winzip iam getting error as "Error: Unable to extract Cloudera-Training-VM-4.1.1.c.vmdk .The size of the extracted file (4446945280) does not match the uncompressed size (151977984) recorded in the Zip file." Could u please tell me which extraction tool u have used to extract the zip so that i can get file of size 4.2GB

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the your downloaded. I used tar I think but don't remember. Try to download it again, it's everything configured!

Comment: Finally iam able to load vm file in my VMWare Workstation.I downloaded Cloudera Quick Start VM . I think it contains one development environment itself.Now iam able to check hadoop commands . Real work starts now planning to write some MapReduce programs.Iam following Definitive Guide 3rd version.Will this be sufficent